# One sided Corner radius using UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: getting distorted corners. Can anyone help to achieve good corners?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cornerradius

**One sided Corner radius using UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: getting distorted corners.**

[image]

Used the following code,

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(view.bounds, 0.5, 0.5) byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(6.0, 6.0)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer1 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer1.frame = view.bounds;
maskLayer1.path  = maskPath1.CGPath;
maskLayer1.strokeColor = view.layer.borderColor;
maskLayer1.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
view.layer.mask = maskLayer1;
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[view setNeedsDisplay];
```

the corner radius getting distorted after applied. 
Side note : Also the border between the views getting thicken when I add the border width to the views, since the border of view getting merged. Any solution or workaround for this is more helpfull.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Most likely you take the size of the view (`view.bounds`) in a life cycle delegate (`viewWill...`) run before the final size of the view is determined. So your path has the wrong size.

Comment: This is a cell and I'm calling this in layoutSubviews method.